# Restrict User to view css code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working for a project in asp.net c#.
I use aspx and css there.
While i link external css file with my asp.x page and after run the page on browser.
When on the view sourse code mode on the browser user can view the css code by click the link tag on the head section. I want to restrict the user to view my css code when click on the link tag of css file in the view source code mode on browser.
Thanks...

Comment: You want the CSS to be applied to the page, yet you don't want the user to be able to view the code of this CSS if they try?

Comment: I don't think it is possible :).

Comment: but impossible is nothing Shekhar sir..

Comment: JavaScript and CSS are client side functionalities, broadly speaking. They are parsed and implemented by the browser on the user's machine. So any JavaScript or CSS on your web page will always be visible to the user through View Source. You cannot control it.

Comment: No solution but thanks to all to show interest..